# how to send request and get response from website(http)

Tags: android

Am new to Android Apps and trying to develop a **search application** that should display the data from a website. Here in the application, it has one **EditText** field and one **ExpandableList** and one Search **Button**.

I need a code to connect my application based on *Data* in EditText and *Item* selected from ExpandableList to the *WEBSITE* and get data from *WEBSITE*.

Comment: You can do so by using a webservice (if one is provided). Please mention what have you tried yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these links for request and responses from the services:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-calling-web-services/